# Getting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.PropertyNotFoundException when parsing fiql expression containing java.util.Calendar attribute

Tags: apache, cxf, java.util.calendar

I use FIQL to query a web service built using Apache CXF 3.0.0-milestone1. When I attempt to reference any attribute of type java.util.Calendar I get a org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.PropertyNotFoundException. I have tracked down the behavior to the FiqlParser.parse(String expression) call and I am able to reproduce it with the simple code below.

Search bean :
import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

```
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date published;
    private Calendar created;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Date getPublished() {
        return published;
    }

    public void setPublished(Date published) {
        this.published = published;
    }

    public Calendar getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Calendar created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

Executable class :

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchCondition;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.fiql.FiqlParser;

public class PlayGround {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        FiqlParser<Book> parser = new FiqlParser(Book.class);
        SearchCondition<Book> condition1 = parser.parse("id=ge=0");
        SearchCondition<Book> condition2 = parser.parse("title==*wind*");
        SearchCondition<Book> condition3 = parser.parse("published=ge=2014-01-01");
        SearchCondition<Book> condition4 = parser.parse("created=ge=2013-01-01");
    }
}
```

PlayGround fails on the following line :

```
SearchCondition<Book> condition4 = parser.parse("created=ge=2013-01-01");
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.PropertyNotFoundException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.fiql.FiqlParser.parseComparison(FiqlParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.fiql.FiqlParser.parseAndsOrsBrackets(FiqlParser.java:252)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.fiql.FiqlParser.parse(FiqlParser.java:187)
    at PlayGround.main(PlayGround.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint in catch block in method org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.fiql.FiqlParser.parseType(String, String, String) you'll see this message for the exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchParseException: Cannot convert String value "2013-01-01" to a value of class java.util.Calendar
```